# PG::Error server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am new to Ruby on rails. I've created two basic demo apps by tutorial `learning by examples`

and suddenly it stops working for my new sample app.

I have generated a controller `Pages` and two actions `home` and `contact` and nothing fancy.

Now, I am not able to open any pages, except the default index.html rails page at `localhost:3000`.  The page at `localhost:3000/pages/home` and `localhost:3000/pages/contact` returns this error.

> PG::Error
>
> server closed the connection unexpectedly     This probably means the
>   server terminated abnormally  before or while processing the request.

and sometimes (usually when I restart postgresql),

> PG::Error
>
> server closed the connection unexpectedly     This probably means the
>   server terminated abnormally  before or while processing the request.
>           **could not send startup packet: Broken pipe**

This is my stack trace

> activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in
>   `initialize' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in`
>   new' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in
>   `connect' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in`
>   initialize' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in
>   `new' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in`
>   postgresql_connection' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in
>   `new_connection' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in`
>   checkout_new_connection' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in
>   `block (2 levels) in checkout' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in`
>   loop' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in
>   `block in checkout'
>   /home/jashwant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in`
>   mon_synchronize' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in
>   `checkout' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in`
>   block in connection'
>   /home/jashwant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in`
>   connection' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in
>   `retrieve_connection' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in`
>   retrieve_connection' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in
>   `connection' activerecord (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in`rescue in call' activerecord
>   (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call' activerecord
>   (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   *run*_3261957284442330683_*call*_599627944998934036__callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback' activesupport (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call' actionpack
>   (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in`call'
>   railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app' railties
>   (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' activesupport (3.2.8)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call' rack
>   (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call' actionpack (3.2.8)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in`call' railties (3.2.8)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call' railties (3.2.8)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:223:in`call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' railties (3.2.8)
>   lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in`call' rack (1.4.1)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
>   /home/jashwant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`
>   service'
>   /home/jashwant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in
>   `run'
>   /home/jashwant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in`
>   block in start_thread'

I am not using database for now. I tried to do `rake db:migrate` but it returns the same error.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 (as some bugs on google were related to ubuntu)

I have found similar questions on SO, but they are experiencing at  some advance stage and thus involves some advance solutions.

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL error logs for more information.

Comment: I've found the answer and specified the same below.

Comment: Weird error for that problem. It should've been giving you "connection refused". "Closed the connection unexpectedly" suggests that you managed to get a connection which was then closed with a TCP  RST or FIN. Weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although, I am not using the database but **specifying the port in configuration in `database.yml` solves the problem**. By default, the `rails new <app_name> --database=postgresql` command does not put a `port` there.

Here's my config.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_app_development
  pool: 5  
  port: 5433
  username: myusername
  password: mypassword
  reconnect: true
```

Comment: Doesn't help in my case. We are using Sunspot with Postgresql. Whenever we start the Sunspot server, then we got PG::UnableToSend: server closed the connection unexpectedly when trying to create model.

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn, check your firewall. And see other questions / answers on SO about this issue. There may be different causes or this error.

Comment: We fixed it by launching the Sunspot server in a fork. Running Sunspot in the same process with Rails Server will trouble the Postgresql connection.

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn, how did you do that?

Comment: I don't recall exactly. Perhaps a `fork { start_sunspot_here }` should do.

Comment: Might be an older post but your the man @Jashwant ,  adding the port into my default group fixed it.  It's rather strange that PG Dev, Prod and even Test worked fine but if I ran a test I got the error listed here, putting the port fixed it!